# Knit Button Results Blank in R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

My knit button in R markdown doesn't work. Everytime I click on knit button it shows just blank.

Rmarkdown file and blank result in Rmarkdown tab
[image]

**However** when I render the file manually in the console using render() it does work and create a desired output in my current directory

```
render("test.Rmd", output_format = "html_document")
```

**Result**

```
processing file: test.Rmd
  |.............                                                                           |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.........................                                                               |  29%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |......................................                                                  |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..................................................                                      |  57%
label: cars
  |...............................................................                         |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................................................             |  86%
label: pressure (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

  |........................................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: test.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\rbbutar\Documents\R\R-4.0.2\library\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\rbbutar\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpu8K2Il\rmarkdown-str123c2b931e63.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --lua-filter "C:/Users/rbbutar/Documents/R/R-4.0.2/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:/Users/rbbutar/Documents/R/R-4.0.2/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua" 

Output created: test.html
```

As shown above the html file created only by using render(), and I have no idea why the knit button doesn't work.

**Things I've tried to solve this**

1. reinstall packages (rmarkdown, tinytex, knitr)
2. restarting R studio

I also look in the internet and found nothing helpful to solve the problem, can anyone help me fix this so my knit button can work as it should?

Comment: I see you have reinstalled packages, and restarted Rstudio... But maybe reinstalling R and then R studio to their current versions, and then installing the packages again may be worth a shot.

Comment: @DanielJachetta Thank you for the advice, I need to consider certain things for reinstalling R for I'm using my office personal computer.